# How to keep failed grep command from outputting into results

Tags: bash

Ok, so I am writing a bash script to check some activeMW information and then output it in JSON so we can use it in a puppet enviroment. I have this one function that is outputting an error on the false condition which is ruining my output

The Function in question :

```
#Displays if ActiveMQ is running
enabled () {
if [ service activemq status | grep 'running' ];
then
enabled="true"
else
enabled="false"

fi
}
```

The output:

```
# ./activemqFactJSON.sh
./activemqFactJSON.sh: line 28: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
{
"activemq" :{
  "installed" : "true",
  "version" : "5.8.0",
  "enabled": "false",
  "engine": ""kahaDB"",
  "size" : "12288"
 }
}
```

What should I do to work around this?

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run the `[` command without closing `]`, since the `|` terminates that call to start a new command that runs `grep`. Drop the `[...]` altogether.

```
enabled () {
if service activemq status | grep 'running';
then
enabled="true"
else
enabled="false"

fi
}
```

There's probably no real need to set a global variable `enabled`; just run the pipe, and let its exit status be the exit status of the function:

```
enabled () {
  service activemq status | grep -q 'running'  # don't produce any output
}

if enabled; then
   echo 'activemq running'
else
   echo 'activemq not running'
fi
```

Comment: Nice! thanks! Uh I have the global variables outputting to heredoc at the end of the script that grabs the output from those functions and outputs them in JSON format